# LongListMultiSelector : How do i change posotion of Checkbox from left to right?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is how my LongListMultiSelector looks on WP8 app when i set IsSelectionEnabled = true

By default, the checkbox is shown on left. How do i change it to show on right handside ?

[image]

XAML Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="GHATIKA" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="cities" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">


            <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="AddrBook" 
                                        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
                                        LayoutMode="List"
                                        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                                        HideEmptyGroups ="true"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate">
    <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="12,8,0,8">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"  
                                Padding="8,0,0,0" Width="62" Height="62"                 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>


<phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
<phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>
<Style x:Key="AddrBookJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
    <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="113,113"/>
    <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="6" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
                               Margin="8,0,0,0" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: have you tried editing the template for that control?

Comment: How to do it ? Can you post the ref XAMl code ? I am new to WP development.

Comment: can u post the code u hav taken in xaml pls?

Comment: @madhukumar Updated my post with code.

Comment: Have u tried wrappanel. You can control ur items in XAML. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth

Comment: Can you post XAML code ? I tried few ways but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the bad news is that the Phone Toolkit dev team has decided to make the style for the LongListMultiSelectorItem an INTERNAL property only so that it always looks like how you find it in the mail apps. This means you cannot override the style using the pre-built DLL's...

The Good news is that it's open source. So you can go and change this, the down side is that you will have to keep a copy of the whole toolkit in your source and if you ever wanted to update with a later copy of the toolkit you will have to manually merge this. We can always raise a change request with them and see if they would be kind enough to change this for us, but in the mean time, if you still want to do it you will have to try one of these options:

If you would like ALL your instances of the LongListMultiSelector to have right aligned check boxes then all you need to do is edit the style named "LongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" in the Themes/Generic.xaml file (Best to use blend as you can move things around easier and see the visual states of the control - But I noticed while trying this myself that blend will rename the Visual States and add a 1 in front, you will want to remove those, and be aware of the animations changing between the states).

If you would like a better solution that would allow you to create your own template for just a single instance of the control, I suggest just going to the LongListMultiSelector and changing the DefaultListItemContainerStyleProperty and DefaultGridItemContainerStyleProperty (plus their backing fields) to public and then you can do something like the following in your code (This is just a reverse of the left to right style, it may not suit what you want as when the checkbox fly's out, the content moves to the right as well):

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
<Style TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelector">
    <Setter Property="DefaultListItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource RightLongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RightLongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                    <Grid MinHeight="52">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="8" x:Key="ExponentialEaseIn"/>
                            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionEnabledStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToExposed" 
                                        From="Closed" To="Exposed"
                                        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToClosed" 
                                        From="Exposed" To="Closed"
                                        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToOpened"
                                        From="Exposed" To="Opened"
                                        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToOpened"
                                        From="Closed" To="Opened"
                                        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-68" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OpenedToClosed"
                                        From="Opened" To="Closed"
                                        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-68" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Exposed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                            Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox"
                                            Duration="0" To="-68"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter"
                                            Duration="0" To="-86"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterCover">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                            Duration="0" To="0.0"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="InfoPresenter" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding ContentInfo}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentInfoTemplate}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" primitives:ClipToBounds.IsEnabled="True">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-24"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerHintPanel" Grid.Column="1" Width="24"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Fill="Transparent"
                                StrokeThickness="0">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-24"/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterHintPanel" Width="24"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                   StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0.0"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="OuterCover" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                              Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="SelectBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,-20,5,0"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0"/>
                                </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```